# Laravel - Nested many-to-many relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to grasp the concept of 'Has-Many-Through' relations.

Here are my current relations,

- The student can join multiple clubs.
- The club consist of many students.
- The club have different positions available and can be assigned to students (i.e President, Chairman..etc)

Here is how my db looks like,

- Students
- Clubs
- club_student (pivot table)
- Positions
- club_position (pivot table)

From Laravel documentation, my understanding of nested relations is to do this,

`$students = Student::with('clubs.positions')->get();`

My question here is,
how do I retrieve all the available information? (Student name, student clubs, student positions &  position points in the respective clubs).

Do I need to foreach loop everything?

```
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        echo $student->name . " -> ";

        foreach ($student->clubs as $club) {
            echo $club->name . " -> ";

            foreach ($club->positions as $position) {
                echo $position->points . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

What if I wanted to just retrieve the student's club position?

Is there a way to directly retrieve `$student->club->position` ?

Comment: the current query should work. what is the current output and what is your exact desired output?

Comment: The direct way would be `$student->clubs->pluck('positions')->flatten()`.

Answer (score 1):

when you set the relations in the models you can retrieve any related information
so if you want to get student club positions you can do

$student->club()->first()->positions()->get() ;

//you can get the first object

$student->club->positions()->get() ;

or if you want to get club students

$club->students()->get();

and so on...